# Определить, кем было сделано изменение - кодом или пользователем

Tags: javascript, jquery

Можно ли как-то в JavaScript или при помощи jQuery определить, кем было сделано изменение - пользователем или кодом?

- **Пример внесения изменений пользователем:** пользователь нажал на checkbox и перевёл его в состояние `:checked` - значит изменение внёс
  пользователь.
- **Пример внесения изменений кодом:** `$('#some-checkbox').prop('checked', true)`

Comment: подписаться на событие `change` и проверить у объекта события поле `isTrusted`

Answer (score 1):

Самый очевидный вариант: отслеживать движение мыши и повесить обработчик на `onclick`.